# Restrict attr_accessible to types of user with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr, attr-accessible

I am creating a forum software. I want admins and mods to be able to *close* certain topics.

Codes are sanitized to show only relevant info.

**Models**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :bio
  has_many :topics, dependent: :destroy
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :name, :last_post_id, :content
end
```

**Schema for user**: admin and mod columns determine admins and mods.

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.datetime "created_at",                         :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                         :null => false
  t.string   "password_digest"
  t.string   "remember_token"
  t.boolean  "admin",           :default => false
  t.text     "bio"
  t.boolean  "mod",             :default => false
end
```

**Schema for topic**: closed column determines topic's closed status.

```
create_table "topics", :force => true do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at",                      :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                      :null => false
  t.integer  "forum_id"
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "last_post_id"
  t.integer  "views"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.boolean  "closed",       :default => false
  t.text     "content"
end
```

I am reluctant to user `attr_accessible :closed` for TOPIC model because it will be vulnerable to malicious PUT request (correct me if I am wrong).

Is there some way for Rails app to be able to access and modify value of `closed` column of TOPIC without using `attr_accessible`, so that only mods and admins can edit them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched on google and found this [ascii cast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/237-dynamic-attr-accessible).

Basically, you are looking for dynamic attr_accessible.

If you currently have

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :name, :content, :closed  
end
```

You ca use dynamic attr_accessible like this :

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :name, :content  
  private  
  def mass_assignment_authorizer  
    super + [:closed]  
  end  
end
```

I hope I is what you are looking for.
Be sure to check the link I gave you for complete reference.